# RegisterInstance with deferred instantiation in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-container

I have a (pretty standard) singleton object in .NET (it has protected constructor and `Instance` property).

I need to register its instance in Unity container, so I call

```
container.RegisterInstance<IFoo>(FooSingleton.Instance);
```

However I would like to avoid its instantiation in container registration method (defer it to only be called if required) as there is a chance it would not be needed and its initialization is expansive.

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an `InjectionFactory` to create your instance on demand and a `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager` to make it a singleton:

```
container.RegisterType<IFoo, FooSingleton>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(), 
    new InjectionFactory(c => FooSingleton.Instance));
```

Comment: Cool, didn't know about the `InjectionFactory`. Thanks!